# What is a shrink, with regard to Haskell's QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm learning the ropes of QuickCheck >= 2.6 but I don't understand what a shrink is. From looking at the [type signature](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.6/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#g:7) shrink looks more like expand! Please illuminate me :)

Comment: Tss, I only know recognize the slight pun in the way you phrased the question, using “shrink” as a noun...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

When QuickCheck finds an input that violates a property, it will first try to find smaller inputs that also violate the property, in order to give the developer a better message about the nature of the failure.

What it means to be „small“ of course depends on the datatype in question; to QuickCheck it is anything that comes out from from the `shrink` function.

It is best explained in a QuickCheck session:

```
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> let prop l = all (/= 5) l
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> quickCheck prop
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 10 tests and 2 shrinks):    
[5]
```

So here QuickCheck was able to give the smallest counter-example, but judging from the comments, it first had a larger list in mind and then reduced it using `shrink`. To have a closer look at what is happening, we use `verboseCheck`:

```
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> verboseCheck prop
Passed:  
[]
Passed: 
[0]
Passed:  
[-2,1]
Passed:  
[-2,2,-2]
Passed:  
[-4]
Failed:  
[-1,-2,5,4,2]
*** Failed! Passed:                       
[]
Failed:                                       
[5,4,2]
Passed:                                    
[]
Passed:                                       
[4,2]
Failed:                                       
[5,2]
Passed:                                     
[]
Passed:                                       
[2]
Failed:                                       
[5]
Passed:                                     
[]
Passed:                                       
[0]
Passed:                                       
[3]
Passed:                                       
[4]
Falsifiable (after 6 tests and 3 shrinks):    
[5]
```

QuickCheck tries a few lists for which the proposition holds, and then finds `[-1,-2,5,4,2]`. Now it reduces the list, by trying sublists of it. You can convince yourself in GHCi that `shrink [-1,-2,5,4,2] == [[],[5,4,2],[-1,-2,2],...` and the second entry is the first that still fails the test. QuickCheck then continues with that and shrinks further: `shrink [5,4,2] == [[],[4,2],[5,2],...`, and further `shrink [5,2]
[[],[2],[5],...`. Lastly it tries to shrink `[5]` further, but none of `shrink [5] ==
[[],[0],[3],[4]]` fail the proposition, so the final count-example is `[5]`.

Comment: Thanks for adding to the above answer. I have a much better idea of what shrinking is about.

Answer (score 10):

A single `shrink` is a stepwise reduction in complexity of some `Arbitrary` test case (an "immediate shrink"). This might be something like `2 -> 1` or `1:[] -> []`. For more complex types there may be multiple ways to "incrementally shrink" a type so you specify all of them in a list.

For example, trees might be shrunk by removing any one leaf, thus if there are `n` leaves then  shrink produces a list of length `n`.