# Uniqueness and other restrictions for Arbitrary in QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, unique, predicate, quickcheck

I'm trying to write a modified `Arbitrary` instance for my data type, where (in my case) a subcomponent has a type `[String]`. I would ideally like to bring uniqueness in the instance itself, that way I don't need `==>` headers / prerequisites for every test I write.

Here's my data type:

```
data Foo = Vars [String]
```

and the trivial `Arbitrary` instance:

```
instance Arbitrary Foo where
  arbitrary = Vars <$> (:[]) <$> choose ('A','z')
```

This instance is strange, I know. In the past, I've had difficulty when quickcheck combinatorically explodes, so I'd like to keep these values small. Another request - how can I make an instance where the generated strings are under 4 characters, for instance?

All of this, fundamentally requires (boolean) predicates to augment `Arbitrary` instances. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by uniqueness? No repeating elements in the string?

Comment: @AndrásKovács Non-repeating elements in the list. Something like `isUnique x = nub x == x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely you want the instance to produce only instances that match the intention of the data type. If you want all the variables to be distinct, the `Arbitrary` instance must reflect this. (Another question is if in this case it wouldn't make more sense to define `Vars` as a set, like `newtype Vars = Set [String]`.)

I'd suggest to check for duplicates using `Set` or `Hashtable`, as `nub` has *O(n^2)* complexity, which might slow down your test considerably for larger inputs. For example:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.List (nub)
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Test.QuickCheck

newtype Foo = Vars [String]

-- | Checks if a given list has no duplicates in _O(n log n)_.
hasNoDups :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
hasNoDups = loop Set.empty
  where
    loop _ []       = True
    loop s (x:xs) | s' <- Set.insert x s, Set.size s' > Set.size s
                    = loop s' xs
                  | otherwise
                    = False

-- | Always worth to test if we wrote `hasNoDups` properly.
prop_hasNoDups :: [Int] -> Property
prop_hasNoDups xs = hasNoDups xs === (nub xs == xs)
```

Your instance then needs to create a list of list, and each list should be randomized. So instead of `(: [])`, which creates just a singleton list (and just one level), you need to call `listOf` twice:

```
instance Arbitrary Foo where
  arbitrary = Vars <$> (listOf . listOf $ choose ('A','z'))
                       `suchThat` hasNoDups
```

Also notice that `choose ('A', 'z')` allows to use all characters between *A* and *z*, which includes many control characters. My guess is that you rather want something like

```
oneof [choose ('A','Z'), choose ('a','z')]
```

---

If you really want, you could also make `hasNoDups` *O(n)* using [hash tables](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables) in the [`ST`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-ST-Safe.html#t:ST) monad.

---

Concerning limiting the size: you could always have your own parametrized functions that produce different `Gen Foo`, but I'd say in most cases it's not necessary. `Gen` has it's own internal size parameter, which is increased throughout the tests (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9992112/1333025)), so different sizes (as generated using `listOf`) of lists are covered.

But I'd suggest you to implement [`shrink`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16968549/1333025), as this will give you much nicer counter-examples. For example, if we define (a wrong test) that tried to verify that no instance of `Var` contains *'a'* in any of its variable:

```
prop_Foo_hasNoDups :: Foo -> Property
prop_Foo_hasNoDups (Vars xs) = all (notElem 'a') xs === True
```

we'll get ugly counter-examples such as

```
Vars ["RhdaJytDWKm","FHHhrqbI","JVPKGTqNCN","awa","DABsOGNRYz","Wshubp","Iab","pl"]
```

But adding

```
shrink (Vars xs) = map Vars $ shrink xs
```

to `Arbitrary Foo` makes the counter-example to be just

```
Vars ["a"]
```

Answer (score 2):

`suchThat :: Gen a -> (a -> Bool) -> Gen a` is a way to embed Boolean predicates in a `Gen`. See the [haddocks](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.8/20140916-162/QuickCheck/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v:suchThat) for more info.

Here's how you would make the instance unique:

```
instance Arbitrary Foo where
  arbitrary = Vars <$> (:[]) <$> (:[]) <$> choose ('A','z')
              `suchThat` isUnique
    where
      isUnique x = nub x == x
```

Comment: Note that in your definition is incorrect - it doesn't typecheck, as you're generating a single-letter strings, while you need a list of strings.

Comment: Also, the probability you will randomly pick a set of unique elements is (n/n)((n-1)/n)...((n-k)/n). If that probability is low then this algorithm will take a while; something to consider if 'a' is very small.